# Is it possible to make ldif config in one file like slapd.conf?

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldif

slapd deprecated slapd.conf, prefer ldif conf, `slapd -F dir` to use the new ldif conf, but the dir must follow the ldif structure

- cn=config.ldif
- cn=config/

  - cn=schema.ldif
  - cn=schema/

is it possible to make the initial ldif config in one file like slapd.ldif ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any LDIF file can include multiple objects. For example, if I want to
create an `organizationalUnit` and a couple of `organizationalPerson`
objects, I can write:

```
dn: ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: users

dn: cn=user1,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
cn: user1
sn: user1
userPassword: {SSHA}lNnn048f5TFMqjb/hWaMibYm5LavDFtK

dn: cn=user2,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
cn: user2
sn: user2
userPassword: {SSHA}vNEUo1M42aG9w4p1zwMkjY2+7xUzeOeF
```

Since recent versions of `slapd` manage configuration as an LDAP
database, we can submit our configuration as LDIF files, just like the
above. For example, the following LDIF file would load the `mdb`
backend and then configure an MDB database for `dc=example,dc=com`:

```
dn: cn=module,cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module
olcModulePath: /usr/lib/openldap
olcModuleLoad: back_mdb.so

dn: olcDatabase=mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: mdb
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=com
olcRootDN: cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com
olcRootPW:: c2VjcmV0
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/openldap/example.com
olcAccess: to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage
```

I like to initialize `slapd` like this:

1. Create a stub `/etc/openldap/slapd.conf.init`:

   ```
   pidfile /var/lib/openldap/run/slapd.pid

   database config
   access to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage
   ```

   The ACL in the above configuration grants `manage` access to the system `root` user when accessing `slapd` via an `ldapi://` socket. This is necessary to provide you with write access to the `cn=config` database.
2. Use that to initialize your `slap.d` configuration:

   ```
   slaptest -f slapd.conf.init -F slapd.d
   ```
3. Start `slapd`, and make sure you enable the `ldapi://` socket:

   ```
   slapd ... -h 'ldap:// ldaps:// ldapi://'
   ```
4. Use `ldapadd` with `EXTERNAL` authentication to add your LDIF based
   configuration:

   ```
   ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:// -f configuration.ldif
   ```

Throughout all of this, you'll need to pay attention to file/directory
ownership: e.g., if you're running `slapd` as the `ldap` user, you'll
need to ensure the `ldap` user is able write to the `slapd.d`
directory.

---

**Update**: [Here](https://github.com/larsks/docker-slapd-example/tree/main) is an example that:

- Builds a custom slapd image designed to be initialized with LDIF files provided at runtime
- An example configuration that deploys the image into kubernetes and mounts a single `ConfigMap` to initialize it.

Comment: So the answer is no, the only solution is convert from conf, I want to use the single ldif so I can mount it from a `ConfigMap`, if this is impossible, have to stick with the slapd.conf.

Comment: No, the answer is "yes". You *can* use a single `ConfigMap` with this model. You just need to build your image so that it initializes itself with a minimal config before processing the LDIF. See my update, which includes an example that does exactly this.